# Mandatory primary keys in Sql Azure

Tags: sql, azure, primary-key, clustered-index

I have been told that in SQL Azure that primary keys are mandatory on each table. However, I've been unable to find anything to back this up.

There are a number of references to mandatory clustered indexes, for example...

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlazure/archive/2010/05/12/10011257.aspx

...but this article is from 2010, so I'm not sure if this is even relevant any more.

Can anyone tell me if primary keys are mandatory in each table in Sql Azure databases?

Comment: A primary key ought to be mandatory on **any** table in a reasonable database design ....

Comment: See [Azure SQL Database Generation Guidelines and Limitations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee336245.aspx) - about halfway down in the document there is a paragraph entitled **Clustered Index Requirement**

Comment: The person offering this advice may be the sort of person who conflates primary keys, clustered indexes and (possibly) identity columns, despite these three concepts actually being distinct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A primary key is not required.  Clustered index - yes.

Answer (score 2):

With Azure SQL Database V12 it is not mandatory anymore to have a clustered index.

See also https://www.itprotoday.com/sql-server/indexes-azure-sql-database-v12.